# Automator / AppleScript to process incoming emails in Mac Mail

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm designing an app that allows users to email me crash reports if my app ever crashes. I'd like to leave Mac Mail running on a computer and when an email comes through, an automator script / AppleScript runs to process the contents of the body of the email.

I've got the entire parsing/processing done in a python script, except I have to manually copy the contents of the email into a file and then run my parser on that file.

What's the best way to set this up so I can the contents of the email be pushed into my parsing script?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the simplest approach is to define a Mail.app Rule.  You can set up filtering conditions to specify the set of incoming email to apply the rule to and among the rule actions you can specify is one to run an AppleScript on incoming messages.  Rules are managed with Mail.app `Preferences` -> `Rules`.  Apple supplies examples of Rule Action scripts with Mac OS X.  Look in `/Library/Scripts/Mail Scripts/Rule Actions` or search the web.

Comment: Cool. I've got that set up but have hit a snag. How do I extract the body of the message in the AppleScript? I'm figuring I can retrieve it from theMessages in the loop "on perform mail action with messages theMessages", but can't seem to find documentation on the parameters of theMessages!

Comment: The AppleScript Editor.app (the name changed in OS X 10.6) is your friend for things like that.  Use its Open Directory menu command to open the script dictionary for Mail.app.  In it you'll see an entry for the class `message` which includes properties like `content` and elements like `mail attachments`.

Comment: Ned - just stumbled into that! Good stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that extracts from email into a file using a mail rule: [MacScripter / Mail rule script for message export.](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=29554) Might be good for sample code for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Dictionary in Applescript Editor to see the properties of mail and you'll quickly be able to see the properties of any mail message.  Here's a quick and dirty example of getting the content of a mail message.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set the_messages to selection
    repeat with this_message in the_messages
        set mytext to content of this_message
    end repeat
end tell
```

Modify the script linked to above that copies output to a temporary file and then pass that file to your Python script to act on.