# AppleScript to process incoming emails in Mac Mail.app

Tags: python, macos, email, applescript

actually my problem is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565784/automator-applescript-to-process-incoming-emails-in-mac-mail) and the answer already brought me very much forward. (Summary: I want my python script running on every incoming email with a certain subject and extract data from the content.)

Anyways I'm a complete newby to AppleScript and cannot find a solution for giving the content of the triggering email as a parameter to my python script.

And actually I only need to pass the html content of the email.

Can anyone point me into the right direction or bring some light into the dark? Thank you very much.

My AppleScript looks like this at the moment and nothing happens although my script should print the email content for now:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
                set theContent to source of eachMessage
                do shell script "python completePathToPyScript.py" & theContent
            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Then my python script does the following for testing:

```
import sys

email_data = str(sys.argv[1])
print email_data
```

Or is the way how I take over the data not correct?

Comment: Where's the code you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Note that you shouldn't use `tell application "Mail"`, because this event is triggered by Mail, and so you have access to all the functionality provided by Mail. `using terms from application "Mail"` is all you need in this case. You can find some more information by typing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and selecting "Mail.app". This will show you Mail's dictionary, and should be a good starting point for further code development. I've now modified it to work without any specific rule, as a workaround for some issues I've experienced in the past:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
        repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
            if subject of eachMessage contains "Express222" then
                set theContent to source of eachMessage
                display alert theContent
            end if
        end repeat
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Comment: How can I test it properly if it is working? I sent the email again but nothing happens ...

Comment: Emails sent to yourself on the same account don't seem to work... If you send an email from one email account to another account, even within mail, it seems to work correctly. Or you can use https://www.express222.com/email_test.php

Comment: Also, a quick way to check that this is working correctly is to put a `display alert "something"` in your code somewhere.

Comment: That is true but I get the feeling that this automated triggering is not working.

Comment: Have you attached the script to a rule?

Comment: I did this: Mail --> Preferences --> Rules --> Add rule --> if subject contains certain string --> run appleScript --> myAppleScript 
But when I receive a matching email nothing happens ... Did I miss sth?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81912/discussion-between-william-t-froggard-and-stefanie-beutke).